# ODFPy documentation

Tags: python, openoffice.org, odf, odfpy

I need to manipulate the ODF file format (open document format, the open office's internal format), and I need to do it in Python.

It seem's ODFPy is a wonderful library for this purpose. Unfortunately the official documentation is very poor, almost unuseful. I can't find almost anything online - maybe it is not so popular?

Is there anyone who can point me at some some information or better documentation?

Answer (score 17):

The documentation is unfortunately horrible, and the generated Python wrapper is lousily documented in code, providing lots of functions whose argument lists look like func(*args).

The reference manual *is* actually useful, but not when you're starting out - it doesn't provide any context of how to use these  functions.  I would suggest starting with the [tutorial](http://odfpy.forge.osor.eu/tutorial/) and all the [examples](https://github.com/eea/odfpy/tree/master/examples).  Even though they may have *nothing* to do with your use case, they will help you get the feel of how the package works.  After you've gotten used to the way the package is structured, you can often make sense of the documentation by combining the API doc with the information in the [OpenDocument Essentials](http://books.evc-cit.info/odbook/book.html) book.

(The relationship is somewhat tenuous at best, but you can often intuit method and attribute values from it.  When working with the spreadsheet, for example, the handy list of office:value-type data in the book provided the necessary constants for building proper TableCell(valuetype=...) instances)

Also, making small documents in OpenOffice and then inspecting the xml and comparing it to the XML generated from ODFPy greatly helps you debug where you might have gone wrong.

Comment: The project links are dead...

Comment: Fixed examples link, but tutorial seems to not exist online anymore (somewhat poor documentation is still available in the source download)

Comment: There is rumor about re-activating the project. https://github.com/eea/odfpy/issues/123

Answer (score 12):

There's a good example of odfpy usage at http://mashupguide.net/1.0/html/ch17s04.xhtml

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting downvoted, the question asks for "...some information or better documentation?", and the link provides information that I have found very useful in interacting with odfpy.

Answer (score 6):

I found more documentation (the web site has been reorganized in the past few years) in [api-for-odfpy.odt](https://github.com/eea/odfpy/blob/master/api-for-odfpy.odt).

Answer (score 3):

It's outdated, a bit, but could help someone.
I have found only one way to work with ODFPY:

1. generate your ODF document (i.e. f1.ods)
2. make copy of it and edit in LibreOffice/OpenOffice or other (i.e. f2.odf)
3. change both files to f1.zip and f2.zip
4. extract both files.

main formatting and data is located in "content.xml" and "styles.xml"

5. compare both formatting
6. make changes in python script
7. iterate 1-7 until you have sufficient result :D:D

Here is some date-time format example, I have made that way:

```
from odf.opendocument import OpenDocumentSpreadsheet
from odf.style import Style, TableCellProperties
from odf.number import DateStyle, Text, Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds
from odf.text import P
from odf.table import Table, TableRow, TableCell

# Generate document object
doc = OpenDocumentSpreadsheet()
table = Table(name="Exported data")
#create custom format in styles.xml
date_style = DateStyle(name="date-style1") #, language="lv", country="LV")
date_style.addElement(Year(style="long"))
date_style.addElement(Text(text=u"-"))
date_style.addElement(Month(style="long"))
date_style.addElement(Text(text=u"-"))
date_style.addElement(Day(style="long"))
date_style.addElement(Text(text=u" "))
date_style.addElement(Hours(style="long"))
date_style.addElement(Text(text=u":"))
date_style.addElement(Minutes(style="long"))
date_style.addElement(Text(text=u":"))
date_style.addElement(Seconds(style="long", decimalplaces="3"))
doc.styles.addElement(date_style)
#link to generated style from content.xml
ds = Style(name="ds1", datastylename="date-style1",parentstylename="Default", family="table-cell")
doc.automaticstyles.addElement(ds)

#create simple cell
tr = TableRow()
tc = TableCell(valuetype='string')
tc.addElement(P(text = "Date-Time"))
tr.addElement(tc)
table.addElement(tr)

#create cell with custom formatting
lineDT = #some date-time variable
tr = TableRow()
tc = TableCell(valuetype='date',datevalue = lineDT.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3],stylename=ds)
tc.addElement(P(text=lineDT.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]))
tr.addElement(tc)
table.addElement(tr)

#save ods
doc.spreadsheet.addElement(table)
doc.save("test.ods", True)
```

I have updated code, a bit, because previous version opened wrong on MS product.

Answer (score 2):

try [ezodf](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ezodf/0.2.1)
they also have a [doc](http://packages.python.org/ezodf/)

Comment: FWIW it looks like ezopdf is not developed anymore

Comment: https://github.com/T0ha/ezodf/issues/37

Answer (score -3):

Okay, here's a quick help:

1. Grab odfpy source code:

   ```
   ~$ svn checkout https://svn.forge.osor.eu/svn/odfpy/trunk odfpy
   ```
2. Install it:

   ```
    ~$ cd odfpy
    ~/odfpy$ python setup.py install
   ```
3. Generate the documentation:

   ```
   ~/odfpy$ epydoc --pdf odf
   ```

   I have uploaded the generated documentation [here](http://www.scribd.com/share/upload/12470875/fzwrhznjbjmlmfkulet).
4. Run this simple example program:

   ```
   from odf.opendocument import OpenDocumentText
   from odf.text import P    
   textdoc = OpenDocumentText()
   p = P(text="Hello World!")
   textdoc.text.addElement(p)
   textdoc.save("helloworld", True)
   ```
5. Read the examples and try to make sense of everything:

   ```
   ~/odfpy$ emacs examples/*.py
   ```

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: This is still the same official documentation that the original poster is (rightfully) complaining about.